# material map error : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an algorithm that lets users enter data or a function and then graphs the function. Essentially, its a surface map [just like here](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Graphulus-Function.html). The graphing works fine. However, I want to add a mapping to add in black lines going from point to point just like in the example. However, I keep getting the standard error of : GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2. I know that this error means that I am trying to draw something that is out of the range of the buffer, but I can't see where I am doing that. I have confirmed that the variables used for the x and  y lengths given to the mapping are indeed the number of x and y indices. For example, I am setting the repeat to 76 and 76 for a mesh that has 76 x entries and 76 y entries and therefore 5776 points.

In the example, they use a parametric geometry and i have to use a standard THREE.Geometry since I am sometimes taking in data and not a function. Other than that, I have followed the example and still get the error. I may be confused about the mapping numbers required for the repeat on the texture. I believe that they are supposed to represent the number of X and Y points and maybe it is supposed to be something else.

Here is the method where I set my meshes:

```
Surface.prototype.setMeshes =function(DataID, callback)
{   var graphMesh={};
    var PlotID=this.Format_id;
    if (PlotID['Chart_dataobj'][DataID]['type']=="Surface")
    {   if (PlotID['Chart_dataobj'][DataID]['sWireFrame']=="Solid")
        {       
            var wireTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'http://www.cadwolf.com/Images/square.png' );
            wireTexture.wrapS = wireTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
            wireTexture.repeat.set( parseInt(PlotID['Chart_dataobj'][DataID].xLength), parseInt(PlotID['Chart_dataobj'][DataID].yLength) );
            wireMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: wireTexture, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
            wireMaterial.map.repeat.set( parseInt(PlotID['Chart_dataobj'][DataID].xLength), parseInt(PlotID['Chart_dataobj'][DataID].yLength) );
            graphMesh = new THREE.Mesh( window[PlotID]['Chart_dataobj'][DataID].surfaceGeometry, wireMaterial );            
            graphMesh.doubleSided = true;                                                       
        }
    }
    graphMesh.id = DataID;
    graphMesh.name = DataID;
    window[PlotID].Scene.add(graphMesh);
    if (typeof(callback)=="function") { callback(); }
}
```

I know that everything is correct with the surface geometry, there is just an error with the number of elements I have matching the numbers for the repeat. Also, if anyone knows what attribute 2 is, that would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Does your geometry have UVs?

Comment: Yes, it has vertices and faces, and all the proper stuff. It works fine as long as I don't try to map an image to it. Is that what you meant by UVs?

Comment: Proper stuff? What is that?

Comment: I just meant that it had the correct number of vertices, faces, colors, and other stuff needed to draw a geometry.

Comment: You need to learn what uv coordinates are, and then you need to inspect your geometry's data structure. Does your geometry have UVs defined?

Comment: If you're talking about the faceVertexUvs parameter then no it is not set and is likely my problem. Looking into it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your geometry to see if you have UVs defined. If not, then the lack of UVs is likely the cause of your error message.

A mesh cannot have a texture applied if the mesh's geometry is missing UVs.

For `THREE.Geometry`, UVs are specified in the property `faceVertexUVs`.

For `THREE.BufferGeometry`, UVs are specified as a geometry attribute.

three.js r.71

Comment: You my good man are a gentleman and a scholar. There is also a function to calculate UVs from vertices http://w3facility.org/question/three-js-generate-uv-coordinate/. Thanks for your time